# Applying PHP script to a file with multiple lines

Tags: php, file, command-line, stdin, lines

Let's say I have to following php script:

```
$str = "be43f751d380a70d13287006a5f7795a";
$arr = str_split($str, 2);
$strT = implode("", substr_replace($arr ,"",-1));
printf('%s:%s' . PHP_EOL, $str, $strT);
```

Outputs: `be43f751d380a70d13287006a5f7795a:b4f5d8a01270af75`

This works with a single string, but what if I want to apply this to more than one string, A file with multiple strings with line endings:

```
cat strings.txt
dc7380f92396b65be0c9dc2fda593acc
e5a391e5b84ebcd51dc467de52f88558
4ec7814976d12b40638fbe311856f84f
```

Desired Output:

```
dc7380f92396b65be0c9dc2fda593acc:d78f29b5ecd2d53c
e5a391e5b84ebcd51dc467de52f88558:ea9eb4bd1c6d5f85
4ec7814976d12b40638fbe311856f84f:4c847d2468b315f4
```

It would be great if we can specify the file in the command line it self:

```
php script.php strings.txt > trimmed.txt
```

Thank you!

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/file http://php.net/foreach

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks, but is that ReadTheF***Manual??

Comment: Well, If you are talking about leaning php then I guess the php documentation on php.net is one of the best resources to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd also advise reading php manual, however not foreach, but file() function. This could be done like:

```
<?php
foreach(file($argv[0]) as $line)
{
    $arr = str_split($line, 2);
    $strT = implode("", substr_replace($arr ,"",-1));
    printf('%s:%s' . PHP_EOL, $str, $strT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a command line solution, run this command:

```
while read str; do php -f myfun.php $str; done < strings.txt
```

where myfun.php is the following PHP script:

```
$arr = str_split($argv[1], 2);
$strT = implode("", substr_replace($arr ,"",-1));
printf('%s:%s' . PHP_EOL, $argv[1], $strT);
```